# Permission denied error during "hadoop namenode -format" command

Tags: 14.04, bash, permissions, hadoop

I am trying to install single node hadoop cluster using [this tutorial](http://www.bogotobogo.com/Hadoop/BigData_hadoop_Install_on_ubuntu_single_node_cluster.php).

I followed all the steps as mentioned the above link says but I am not able to format the namenode using command `hadoop namenode -format`.

It gives this error:

```
bash: /usr/local/hadoop/bin/hadoop: Permission denied
```

Answer (score 0):

If it says permission denied, you probably need sudo.

Try this command instead:

```
sudo hadoop namenode -format
```

It may not be needed, but as you are having issues it may help. The tutorial suggests it will be modifying folders in `/usr` - this could be the issue.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like the hadoop user does not have the required permissions.

Try:
`sudo chown -R hduser:hadoop /usr/local/hadoop`

This command will make `hduser` (part of group `hadoop`) to be the owner of the directory `/usr/local/hadoop`. To do that recursively i.e. for all files and directories (and all files and directories within any directory), -R option is used.